# SQL statement to get IDs with a specific condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called Cats with two columns (shortId, LongId)

And another table called cat-to-cat-dependency that has two columns (sourceShortId, targetShortId)

I want to return a list of all the source Cat LongIds given a target Cat LongId.

My sql statement is

```
SELECT C.LongID
FROM CAT C INNER JOIN
     CAT-TO-CAT-DEPENDENCY CD
     ON CD.sourceShortId = CAT.shortId
WHERE CAT.LongID = '1234'
```

But this always just returns the value that I input.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select C1.LongId
from cat-to-cat-dependency CD
join Cats C1 on C1.shortId = CD.sourceShortId
join Cats C2 on C2.shortId = CD.targetShortId
where C2.LongId = '1234'
```